# Removing downvoted questions

Tags: discussion

What's the best course of action to take if you notice your question is getting downvoted a lot? Should it be removed and a new better formatted question be asked, or should edits to the original question be made in the hope that it will be improved?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should edit.

If you remove too many of your own posts, you risk getting a ban.

So instead, improve your question. Tell us what you've tried. Tell us what you've learned so far. Tell us what you think the issue is, and why.
If possible, provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

EDIT:
As @Deduplicator points out, sometimes a question can't be salvaged. For example, a question of the type "Should I use Java or C#" (a [Gorilla vs Shark question](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)) or "What PHP framework should I use" (a [shopping question](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)).
If your question is like that, then deletion is best - and avoid such questions in the future.

Note that questions that ask what software to use are explicitly off-topic on Stack Overflow, but can *sometimes* be migrated to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).
First, you check if it meets their [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). If it does, you can flag it for moderator attention with a custom flag and ask for migration. If it does not, edit it until it does, and then ask for migration.

Comment: It should be rare, but if you cannot bring it up to minimal acceptable standards whatever you do, then deletion is the only thing possible to minimize the damage.